# ICP Accelometer Arduino

Tags: sensors, analogread

I need to connect piezoelectric accelerometer to Arduino. Precisely, it's this one: http://www.pcb.com/Products.aspx?m=352C34

Specs show that it generates 100 mV/g, but when I connected it between ground and analog input with 1M pulldown resistor, analog input stays at 0.

Arduino analog input resolution and accuracy is absolutely fine for now.

Could someone point me to right direction in connecting this kind of sensor to Arduino?

Comment: How do you provide power to the device?

Comment: Can you show your exact circuit?

Comment: That device appears to both require a non-trivial interface circuit, and to be intended for measuring *vibration*, not steady accelerations such as gravity.  It has a minimum frequency of one cycle every 2-3 seconds.  Also note the series capacitor in their sample setup.